# Merging document with OpenOffice from flex (air)

Tags: apache-flex, pdf, air, ms-word, openoffice.org

i'm searching a method to merge some data from an air application to a template made with word (.doc).
I've search on the web for exemple, look at the open office API, but did'nt find anything.
1- do you think it's possible from air to make a document (pdf as possible) from a existing template in .doc ?
If not, i read that livecycle can do pdf from template (template in pdf, with xsd to do the relation beetween data and template) but do know a simple way to convert existing template in .doc to template in pdf?
Every clues will be welcome to help us.
Thanks !

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any PDF libraries that would let you provide a native Flex solution for merging data from your Flex application with a PDF form, but if you're able to do the merging of data with the form outside of Flex, then there's plenty of options.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to make a pdf document with [AlivePDF](http://www.alivepdf.org/) but I don't think it's currently possible to open a .doc file, maybe a .docx since its basically a xml in a zip file.

I don't think a word document as a template would be a good choice, I would recommend using an image.